# How to resolve the issue: reference the NuGet package from your main application project in order to reference the platform-specific implementation?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am new to Xamarin and I was following this official of microsoft [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/create-a-mobile-app-with-xamarin-forms/5-exercise-create-phone-number-translator-app). In my code when I am running this line:

```
try
{
   PhoneDialer.Open(translatedNumber);
}
```

It throws the following error:

> {Xamarin.Essentials.NotImplementedInReferenceAssemblyException: This functionality is not implemented in the portable version of this assembly. You should reference the NuGet package from your main application project in order to reference the platform-specific implementation.
> at Xamarin.Essentials.PhoneDialer.PlatformOpen (System.String number) [0x00000] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Essentials\PhoneDialer\PhoneDialer.netstandard.tvos.watchos.cs:9
> at Xamarin.Essentials.PhoneDialer.Open (System.String number) [0x00000] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Essentials\PhoneDialer\PhoneDialer.shared.cs:17
> at Phoneword1.MainPage+d__6.MoveNext () [0x000da]

[image]

Comment: did you follow all of the instructions when setting up Essentials?  Is the package installed in both the platform and shared projects?  What project are you executing this code in?

Comment: Yes i did. I installed Xamarin.Essential in my mainpage.cs foler( one which is outside android and iOS).  I am executing code in mainpage.cs

Comment: That sounds like you **didn't** install it **in the platform-specific project**. (e.g. the Android or iOS or UWP project). It is needed there. (And probably also in the shared-code project, where you put it, so leave it there also.) Perhaps confusing wording; The "main application" is different on each platform - its the first code that runs on that platform. The cross-platform page is not that.

Comment: This is the ss of my directories. I followed each step properly from Microsoft. Please let me know if you still see nay issue. thanks!

Comment: that image only shows the packages of the shared project.  Do you also have the package installed in the iOS and Android projects?  This is the **third** time you have been asked this.

Comment: I didn't install any specific package installed for android and ios. Do i need to install Xamarin.Essential in their references also?

Comment: Normally, Xamarin.Essential package would be installed by default. If you use this package, you need to install it for all the platforms.